# Google Analytics API Error for inserting unsampled report

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the ruby gem google-api-client version 0.8.6. I've got the account and oauth stuff all set up. I can query the read only aspects of the analytics api, including listing unsampled reports. However, if I try to insert an unsampled report, I get a 400 error: **Field title is required**.

I am passing in the title, so either this error message is incorrect, or I don't know what.

Here are the params:

```
{"accountId"=>xxx,
 "webPropertyId"=>"UA-xxx-1",
 "profileId"=>"xxx",
 "title"=>"Browsers",
 "start-date"=>"2014-01-01",
 "end-date"=>"2014-01-31",
 "metrics"=>"ga:pageviews"}
```

Here is the URL the gem calls:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/xxx/webproperties/UA-xxx-1/profiles/xxx/unsampledReports?dimensions=ga%3Abrowser&end-date=2014-01-31&kind=analytics%23unsampledReport&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&start-date=2014-01-01&title=Browsers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters for this request should be sent in the request body, not as query parameters append to the URL. Based on this error, what's probably happening is Google Analytics is looking at the request body, and the first thing it looks for is a `title` field. When it doesn't find one (since yours are in the URL), it responds with the error saying a title is required.

As far as I can tell, it looks like this gem is incorrectly implementing these API calls. You may want to try just doing the POST yourself in code.

**Update:** you can try playing around with [this method in the APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.filters.insert) to get a better sense for how the request should be formatted.

Comment: thank you, this problem has been torturing me for a long time